# Two buttons to make a div content, scroll up and down

Tags: html, css, mootools

I have a div with 90px of height and `overflow:hidden` with dynamic content. Side by side, i've two buttons to make scroll is content.

Suppose:

```
<div id="up">Up</div>
<div style="width:100px; height: 90px; overflow:hidden;display:block">
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla     bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla     bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
</div>
<div id="down">Down</div>
```

The script I am using (with MooTools), without success, is:

```
<script>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var down = $('down');
    var up   = $('up');
    var div  = $('contentdiv');

    up.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
        event = new Event(event).stop();
        var myFx = new Fx.Scroll(div).start(0, 0.5 );
    });

    down.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
        event = new Event(event).stop();

        var myFx = new Fx.Scroll(div, {
            offset: {
                x: 0,
                y: 1
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Why doesn't this work?

A full example is available at http://jsfiddle.net/Rv5Mn/1/

Comment: To increase your chances of anyone wanting to answer your question, you should consider adding a live example, for instance on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Also, if this code is copied straight from what you have, you are missing a closing bracket on your second div and a typo in your `hwight` attribute ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Code available at http://jsfiddle.net/Rv5Mn/1/

Comment: this is mootools 1.1 code and wouldn't work in 1.2+

Comment: Which version of mootools do you have/are loading in your page?

Comment: Rui, não te esqueças de aceitar as respostas que resolvam a pergunta. O Stackoverflow dá pontos a quem responde e tb a quem aceita respostas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using a newer version of Mootools (1.3/1.4):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    var down = $('down');
    var up = $('up');
    var div = $('contentdiv');

    up.addEvent("click", function (event) {
        event.stop();
        var myFx = new Fx.Scroll(div);
        myFx.start(0, div.getScroll().y - 80);
    });

    down.addEvent("click", function (event) {
        event.stop();
        var myFx = new Fx.Scroll(div);
        myFx.start(0, div.getScroll().y + 80);
    });
});
```

**Note:**

- in your html you had no `$('contentdiv');`, i mean you forgot to give `id="contentdiv"`
- if you want to use Mootools's `.stop();` you need to use `addEvent` instead of `addEventListener`
- Your fiddle is not related to this question (!)

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnGMk/1/)